# HP QC ALM How can I list the recently checked in scripts and tests?

Tags: hp-quality-center, hp-alm

We are working with HP QC ALM v11.00. We have enabled version control in the same.
I need to keep an eye on all scripts (Business Components and Test Resources) that are recently modified in the same. I need to do this to have an overview on the changes happening in the code, make sure it conforms to the coding standards, is reviewed etc.

I cannot seem to find an obvious way to do this. Can someone help?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You might require to build a tool which reports you the changes done in the resource. You can build it around OTA/Rest api provided by quality center using any programming language you want. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I have tried to get some reporting based on DB access.
I would request help with the OTA / Rest Api. I am using QC 11.00. I could not find the information in the OTA Help manual available in the Site Admin section.

Comment: you need to be familiar with programming inorder to build this type tool. Both OTA and Rest API has audit/history support which can provide you base to construct reporting around it, may be in excel or some other form. Can you please define set of requirements on this and send it on gcchavda[at]gmail[dt]com so that I can check it on my free time to see the feasibility of what you need exactly.